# How do you achieve successful authorization with OAuth 2.0 Client ID credentials in an ubuntu server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, ubuntu-20.04

I have a python file which has OAuth 2.0 credentials. In my local machine, the authorisation flow is successful.
I am using a desktop app here.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifojd.png)
I have enabled all necessary APIs.
When I try to authorise the same through a ubuntu server, it is not working. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMaCA.png)

I want the authorisation to run successfully on the ubuntu server. Should i change to a web application type authorisation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example